# How to get the red component from an image C#

Tags: c#, winforms

How to get the red component from an image, in C# (windows forms).
I want to get the Red component in a new matrix.
I tried something like this with a bmp:

```
byte[,] MatrixImage= new byte[256, 256]; // is my matrix where every pixel of my image is stored
byte[,] MatrixRed= new byte[256, 256]; 
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(256, 256);

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
                {      
                    var red = Color.FromArgb(MatrixImage[i, j], 0, 0);
                    bmp.SetPixel(i, j, red);
                    var getRedPixel = bmp.GetPixel(i, j);
                    MatrixRed[i, j] = (byte)getRedPixel;

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetPixel Returns a Color object so you're probably looking for this :
MatrixRed[i, j] = (byte)(getRedPixel.R);

Comment: I don't have any errors anymore. But why my image is like this: https://ibb.co/CsJ1QZs?

Comment: byte[,] MatrixImage= new byte[256, 256]; This line cant be corrrect. Why would the original image have the same array size then the one with only red as a channel

Comment: My guess is that array contains all the image information, so you might be mixing the channels togheter.